# Automapping Resource model to Entity in WebAPI - PUT nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper, blazor, webapi

I am attempting to modify data via WebAPI using a automapped resource model on my EFCore entity class.
I have managed to get GET, GET(by id) and POST working fine using this method.

Now the problem I face is with an Automapper nullable typepair error message I get when trying to do a PUT with this Resource.

**Here is my Entity:**

```
[Table("BlazorWebApiDemo")]
    public partial class BlazorEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column("First Name")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        [Column("Last Name")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string? Address { get; set; }
    }
```

**Here is my Resource Model:**

```
    public class BlazorEntityModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

**My Automapper profile:**

```
    public class BlazorEntityProfile : Profile
    {
        public BlazorEntityProfile()
        {
            this.CreateMap<BlazorEntity, BlazorEntityModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.NullSubstitute(""))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.NullSubstitute(""))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.NullSubstitute(""));
        }
    }
```

*Note:* I have added NullSubstitute for each member as I thought this would resolve the error. It didn't.

**And my PUT method in the API controller.**

```
        [HttpPut("id:int")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<BlazorEntityModel>> UpdateBlazorItem(int id, BlazorEntityModel blazorEntityModel)
        {
            try
            {
                var updatedBlazorEntity = await blazorRepository.GetBlazorById(id);
                if (blazorEntityModel == null) return NotFound($"LetItem with the ID: {id} not found");

                mapper.Map(blazorEntityModel, updatedBlazorEntity);

                if(await blazorRepository.SaveChangesAsync())
                {
                    return mapper.Map<BlazorEntityModel>(updatedBlazorEntity);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                                  e);
            }

            return BadRequest();
        }
```

*Note:* blazorRepository.GetBlazorById(id) retrieves a BlazorEntity.

**SaveChangesAsync**

```
        public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            return await(context.SaveChangesAsync()) > 0;
        }
```

Swagger test:

[image]

Error message:

[image]

any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would cause the error, but your action attribute should probably be `HttpPut("{id:int}")` (instead of `HttpPut("id:int")`). Otherwise the `id:int` part is considered part of the URL, not specifying a replacement parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code on Mapper Profile is inverted, try change `this.CreateMap<BlazorEntity, BlazorEntityModel>()` to `this.CreateMap<BlazorEntityModel, BlazorEntity>()`

Or you can use `.ReverseMap()` to use this configuration in both way

```
this.CreateMap<BlazorEntity, BlazorEntityModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.NullSubstitute(""))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.NullSubstitute(""))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.NullSubstitute(""))
    .ReverseMap();
```

Note: you dont need to specify `string` as `string?` because `string` already is a nullable type

Comment: Okay great, this helped me get rid of the nullable typepair error but I am still getting as similar error 

'System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported and should be avoided since they can lead to security issues. Path: $.TargetSite.DeclaringType.'

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. Figured out what the above error message is. Turns out I can't use the ID [Key] field in my resource model. Commenting this out sorted the issue. Will accept your answer though Jefferson. Thanks!

Comment: `string already is a nullable type` - I don't think that's necessarily true if [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) are enabled